# Searching for elements in array and return matching elements in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document

```
db.c.save({a:[{u:3},{u:6},{u:123}]});
```

I want to  fetch matching elements from the array. So I use the following query to do it.

```
db.c.find({'a.u':{$in:[3,123]}},{'a.$':1});
```

This gives me `{ "a" : [ { "u" : 3 } ] }` but I guess it should return `{ "a" : [ { "u" : 3 }, { "u" : 123 } ] }`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) only returns the first match so you can't use it to do what you are trying to do.

However, you can use either [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) or [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/). The following code does what you want using the aggregation framework :

```
db.c.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$a"},
  { $match  : { "a.u" : {$in :[3,123]} } },
  { $group  : {_id : "$_id",a : { $push : "$a" } } }
])
```