# how to get records from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have the mongodb colllection like

```
{
   id : 'd8fsd7f8sdfsd8f8ds7fsd8',
   books : [
          {"author" : "['b1']" , "date" : 2-3-00, name: 'a'},
          {"author" : "['b1', 'b2']" , "date" : 4-10-00, name: 'b'},
          {"author" : "['b2']" , "date" : 5-3-00, name: 'c'},
          {"author" : "['b2']" , "date" : 6-12-00, name: 'd'}, ]
 }
```

How can i get the data contain author "b2" by mongo query like

```
{
   id : 'd8fsd7f8sdfsd8f8ds7fsd8',
   books : [
         {"author" : "['b1', 'b2']" , "date" : 4-10-00, name: 'b'},
          {"author" : "['b2']" , "date" : 5-3-00, name: 'c'},
          {"author" : "['b2']" , "date" : 6-12-00, name: 'd'}, ]
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so what and where did it go wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching for elements in array and return matching elements in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752316/searching-for-elements-in-array-and-return-matching-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your collection name is `books`. You can do that [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) framework

```
db.books.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$books'},
    { $match: {'books.book1': {$eq: "b2"}}},
    { $group: {books: {$push: '$books.book1'}}})
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do it, notice how the subdocument is filtered

Comment: What I meant is you need to filter the subdocument, MongoDB won't do that for you.