# MongoDB Java, query elements in the array and return selected value,

Tags: mongodb

I have following records in Mongo 2.4,

```
    {
    "name": "AsiaEurope",
    "events": [{
    "action": "updated",
    "someHeaderField": "field1",
    "version":"3.3",
    "eventValue": {
        "local": "newZealand",
        "remote": "India"
    }
    }, {
    "action": "new",
    "someHeaderField": "field1",
    "version":"3.3",
    "eventValue": {
        "local": "Japan",
        "remote": "England"
    }
    }, {
    "action": "finished",
    "someHeaderField": "field1",
    "version":"3.2",
    "eventValue": {
        "local": "Brasil",
        "remote": "Turkey",
        "middlebox": "Russia"
    }
    }, {
    "action": "updated",
    "someHeaderField": "field1",
    "version":"3.2",
    "eventValue": {
        "local": "Canada",
        "remote": "Cuba"
    }
    }]
}
```

I want to write a Mongo query to get `eventValue` in Java where action equals to `updated` and name is `AsiaEurope`. There could be multiple elements in the `Events` (array) whose action equals to updated.

How to write the query and how to fetch `EventValue` in Java?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you want to get output like : `db.collection.find({"name":"AsiaEurope","events.action":"updated"},{"_id":0,"events.eventValue":1})`

Comment: try this in your shell. Converting it into java is not a big deal.

Comment: db.conference.aggregate([{$match: { name:"AsiaEurope"} },
                         {$unwind: "$events"},
                         {$match: {"events.action":"updated"} },{$group: {_id:"$_id", events:{$push:"$events"}}}])

Comment: Above is the answer, I only need to study now how to using Java client to get the fields. By the way, How to format code in comment section?

Comment: a good reference is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752316/searching-for-elements-in-array-and-return-matching-elements-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did not tested it with mongo 2.4 (tested with mongo 3.0)**, but you can use something like following :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$match": {
    "name": "AsiaEurope"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$events"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "events.action": "updated"
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "eventValue": "$events.eventValue"
    }
}).pretty()
```

And equivalent java code is :

```
    ArrayList<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("name","AsiaEurope" ));
    BasicDBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$events");
    BasicDBObject match2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("events.action","updated"));
    BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("eventValue","$events.eventValue").append("_id",0));

    pipeline.add(match);
    pipeline.add(unwind);
    pipeline.add(match2);
    pipeline.add(project);
    AggregationOutput cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

This will give you expected output.